# Windows 10 - How to find executable of apps in Volume Mixer?

Tags: windows-10, volume-mixer

I'm trying to setup a hotkey to mute my Xbox party audio. I assumed the application I needed to mute was GameBar.exe, which I found in task manager, but it turns out there are 2 *Xbox Game Bar*s in Volume Mixer, and that's not the right one. How can I find the executable of the other *Xbox Game Bar*?

[image: Screenshot of task manager and volume mixer]

Comment: Are you sure A) volume control maps to executables and B) this is the right way to accomplish what you want?

Comment: A) I know it does at least some of the time, but I don't know if it always does. B) It's the easiest thing I could come up with. Even if it wasn't, I would still be curious to know the answer.